# Turn off high side switch

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, mosfet-driver, charge-pump

I am trying to turn off my N-channel MOSFET which is driven by a charge pump.

[image]

It takes too long to discharge the pump through the gate-resistor to ground, therefore the power dissipation is very high.

[image]

Any advice to lower the amount of time it takes to turn the MOSFET off?

Downsizing the charge pump and the resistor both leads to a shorter time, but then the charge pump can't reach its potential voltage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actively discharge  C2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBmHhk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming you switch the charge pump on and off with some sort of logic, derive the off control as the complement of that.